# Separate tables for the user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm constructing a database for my forum. One of my tables holds all the user information(username, age, gender, etc). It contains 26 columns, including several LONGTEXT like the "About Me".

My question, for performance and speed when using MySQL queries, would it be better to create two separate tables for the user: One with important information(username, password) and a second with less-important information(about me, age, gender, etc)?

Thank you!

Comment: You know, there are dozens of already-written forum software packages. Why write your own, and probably get it wrong, when you can use one that actually works and is supported by people not asking simple questions like this one on SO?

Comment: you can do this as long as you properly use indexes for commonly read columns and write efficient SQL statements to extract data

Comment: @Sanath : Thanks. I understand I can do it, I just wondered if it would benefit the performance in any way.

Comment: @TomMcPadden Simply because : What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ? What specific problems have you encountered ? Also...[Faq]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're bringing back the data one user at a time it's probably just best to keep the data all in the same table. I would only break it out if you were going to pull back multiple users (and a lot of them) including the LONGTEXT, or if you end up with many of the same thing belonging to the user such as addresses, etc.